# Utility to update Django locales for a non-technical translator?

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

If I need to translate my website in languages that I do not know, I'd like to give my translator only her locale file or only locale folder (to not expose the source code) and have a way to update the locale on a test server automatically without much technical work.

90% chance that the translator will have Windows and be not a technical guru like us. It means no Mercurial, no Putty is possible. Nor is an option to send emails back and forth between us and me to update the translation, so that she could check it on a live site.

I'll probably need a password-protected view, a django-admin command and a Mercurial subrepo to let them download/upload/roll back translations without interfering with the whole website.

Is there a solution like this already?

**update**: Right now, I need to translate only the static content (templates and strings in the code), not user-generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to translate a django app or user created content?

For the first case you can check this online service https://www.transifex.net/

For the second case, there are several django apps with different approach to help translating content. Check out http://djangopackages.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, great! That's exactly what I was looking for! BitBucket support is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable translation from within your project with [django-rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta#readme).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a test server,  I would just have a sFTP site for the translator with a symbolic link from the Django instance to that ftp directory for the translation directory(s).

The translator will probably be familiar with this set up and you don't have to write any code ...